# Connection issues to RDS DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I am trying to connect to my RDS DB using SSMS from my laptop to the below RDS endpoint and getting the below mentioned error msg, my DB in the RDS console says Available: **aa1s53y3s589rvg.cul7cuvnpne2.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71d5Q.png)

Comment: Is your DB accessible from the Internet? And is port 1433 open on your security group?

Comment: Please find below the configuration of my RDS SG, please let me know if i have made any stupid mistake in leaving something very basic, go ahead and shout at me i am here to listen as my motive is to learn however possible, Thanks in advance for all your help: https://imgur.com/dppOxeb

Answer (score 0):

You don't need http and https.
Add a line in your security group for port TCP 1433 (custom) and allow it from My IP (in the drop down list).

Keep in mind that your IP address (a signed from your service provider) may change. So you need to update this line with your new IP from time to time.

Comment: Dear check below URL if it's what you want me to do, as i am still getting the same connection error message.  https://imgur.com/AWxXqwv

Comment: yes.  
Is your DB on a public subnet?

Comment: Dear it's an RDS instance and it part of a subnet group which have one subnet Public as well with attached IGW.

Comment: When you created the RDS instance, did you specify that it's publicly accessible?

Comment: Now i made it sure that it is publicly available, please the RT that it's VPC is associated with that has IGW associated as well. Please check the screenshot below:
https://imgur.com/IE3ASVQ

Comment: Make sure your default security group has port 1433 allowed for your IP address. And also make sure the 2 subnets (subnet-02e87.... and subnet-02ee4...) have an Internet Gateway in their routing table.

Comment: Thanks @Algeriassic dear, finally i was able to connect to my instance from my local SSMS after adding port 1433 for my IP address !!

Comment: @MasoodKhan that was the first thing I suggested to do. 
Please mark the answer as the best answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, yes i remember your comment in the beginning but the only difference back then and now is initially the RDS was for my Elastic Beanstalk which i had problem accessing from my local SSMS, but just a few days ago i deleted it and made a standalone RDS instance created a DB and then tried your suggestions again and it worked, Thanks again...i believe there was something lacking by default in the RDS that's created with EB...don't know what exactly still...

Comment: Happy that your problem is fixed